# How to make webpack-dev-server apply my changes?

Tags: webpack, frontend

Trying to use WP dev server. My config file is the folowing:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './frontend/app.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},

watch: false,

watchOptions: {
  aggregateTimeout: 100
},

module: {
  loaders: [
    { test:  /\.js$/, loader: 'babel'},
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' },
    { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html'}
  ]
},
devServer: {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8080
},

externals: {
  lodash: "_",
  jquery: "$"
},

resolveLoader: {
   root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
}
```

};

i launch webpack with the command: 
    **webpack-dev-server --inline** 
and then go to 
http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/

So it opens fine, but when i make some changes, like
      **alert("Done!"); --> alert("Donasdadae!");**
page is being reloaded automatically, but i still see the 'old' alert: "Done!", so changes have not been applied(but the page is reloaded! it drives me crazy)

What can I do about it?
Thx